# Target "debug" doesn't exist in the Project

Tags: ant, command-prompt, apk

I have tried to **create APK file using the "ant debug" command**. But when i tried i got the following error

```
Build Failed
Target "debug" does not exist in the Project "androiddemo"
Total Time: 0 Seconds


Build Failed
Target "release" does not exist in the Project "androiddemo"
Total Time: 0 Seconds
```

Checked with release command also. Getting the same error. Could you please guide me to get APK file of Android application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a **stupid mistake with my command**. The actual command is

```
"ant -debug"
```

But **APK file is not created**. Is anything i missed in that?

Comment: did you ever figure out why the apk is not being generated? I'm having the same issue